# Touchpad not responding

Tags: dual-boot

Hello I recently shift from windows to ubuntu but as I install Ubuntu the touchpad is not responding at all. I tried almost everything I can get from Google but it is not working at all. In windows it is working fine but in ubuntu it's not working.
It would be grateful if someone could help me resolve this issue.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1315147/edit) your question and add more details about what type of system you are using and what version of Ubuntu you are installing?  More details you can give to us the more we can help you!  Thank you!

Comment: I am using Lenovo V15-IIL laptop and I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 version which I upgraded to 20.04 but the problem persists in both versions.